# laravel job payload index job undefined

Tags: php, laravel

My job sometimes throws an exception:

```
Undefined index: job

#1 D:\home\site\repository\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\Job.php(192): Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\Job->failed(Object(Exception))
#2 D:\home\site\repository\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue.php(47): Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\Job->fail(Object(Exception))
```

The corresponding function in the framework (Job.php):

```
protected function failed($e)
    {
        $payload = $this->payload();

        [$class, $method] = JobName::parse($payload['job']);
    ...
```

So it seems that job is not set in payload. Where and how does it get set? I never do this manually and I think this should always be set automatically by laravel!?
I did not have this issue before I upgraded to laravel 8 from 5.8

Comment: What type of data you are you passing to the job?

Comment: When you upgraded, did you follow each upgrade guide carefully.

Comment: If you edited a job did you remember to:

php artisan queue:restart

Comment: @Basharmal yes, I restarted the queue

Comment: what it is saying is that sometimes payload is empty

Comment: These traits -> Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue used in your job?

Comment: @Kent yes both. I just ugly fixed it by wrapping ->fail() in a try catch